# Construction of connected set in expanded complex plane

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, euclidean-domain

I'm trying to prove a theorem(I'm not sure whether it's right)

$X\cup\{\infty\}$ is connected in $\overline{C}$(expanded complex plane) if and only if all connected components of $X$ in $C$ are unbounded.

This problem arises because the definition of simple connected domain in (Complex analysis)(Ahlfors L.V.)

I'd proved that if all connected components of $X$ is unbounded then $X\cup\{\infty\}$ is connected in $\overline{C}$,but when I try to prove another, I have no idea.

I would be very grateful if someone could answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converse fails.

Let $A_1,A_2,A_3,...$ be the subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ given by
$$
A_n
=
\left\{
re^{i\theta}
{\,{\large{\mid}}\,}
r\ge{\small{\frac{1}{n}}}
\;\text{and}\;
\theta={\small{\frac{\pi}{2n}}}
\right\}
$$
and let $X$ be the subset of $\mathbb{C}$ given by
$$
X
=
\{0\}
\,{\large{\cup}}
\left(
\,
{\small{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty}}
A_n
\right)
$$
**Claim:**$\;X\,\cup\{\infty\}$, with the topology inherited from
$\overline{\mathbb{C}}$,
is connected,
whereas $X$, with the topology inherited from $\mathbb{C}$, is not connected, and has the bounded set $\{0\}$ as a connected component.

**Proof:**

First we show that $X\,\cup\{\infty\}$ is connected in $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$.

For each positive integer $n$, let $B_n=A_n\cup\{\infty\}$.

Noting that $A_n$ is connected in $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$, and $B_n$ is the closure of $A_n$ in $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$, it follows that $B_n$ is connected.

Let $Y=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$.

Since the sets $B_n$ share a common point, it follows that $Y$ is connected.

Then the closure of $Y$ is also connected.

But the closure of $Y$ is just $Y\,\cup\{0\}$ which equals $X\,\cup\{\infty\}$, hence $X\,\cup\{\infty\}$ is connected in $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$.

Next we show that $X$ is not connected in $\mathbb{C}$, and has the set $\{0\}$ as a connected component.

For each $n$, the identity
$$
X
=
A_n
\cup
\bigl(
X{\setminus}A_n
\bigr)
$$
yields a partition of $X$ into two closed sets, hence $X$ is not connected.

Moreover, since each $A_n$ is connected, we get, from the above partition, that each $A_n$ is a connected component of $X$.

Finally, since the connected components of $X$ partition $X$, it follows that $\{0\}$ is a connected component of $X$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer！